# Table data in SQLite database shows fine in Simulator but does not appear when deployed to device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Table data in SQLite database shows fine in Simulator but does not appear when deployed to device.

Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the database is really installed to device, or that it really is being written to a writeable place on the device.

I had a similar problem, because it is much easier to write anywhere with the simulator.